# Getting a query result into a Variable then passing it to a command

Tags: c#, sql

Here is my code. I am trying to get a result of a SQL query stored in `query1` variable, and want to use that result in a SQL query stored in `query` variable. Messagebox is irrelevant, I just wrote it to see if I am getting the correct results from listbox1 or not.If i hardcode the query1's result into command parameters, it works perfectly.

```
private void btnAddCoarse_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());


    string query1 ="SELECT ogrenciNo FROM ders,ogrenci,Enrollment WHERE ogrenciId=ogrenciNo AND dersId=dersKodu AND ogrenci.email='" + mainform.Username + "' AND Enrollment.dersId='"+listBox1.SelectedValue+"'";
    string query = "INSERT INTO Enrollment(dersId,ogrenciId) VALUES (@dersId, @ogrenciId)";

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dersId", listBox1.SelectedValue);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ogrenciId",//this is where i need the query1//);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        PopulateList2();
    }
}
```

Comment: You use Parameters with the second query but not the first?  - Do it for both!

Comment: @AlexK. one of them is select other one is insert statement,i need parameters for insert for it to know what its going to insert.I dont see why i need parameters for other one .

Comment: @PoyrazKürkçüoğlu Using sql parameters is a good practice and is mandatory for avoiding sql injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this

```
private void btnAddCoarse_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());


       string query1 ="SELECT ogrenciNo FROM ders,ogrenci,Enrollment WHERE ogrenciId=ogrenciNo AND dersId=dersKodu AND ogrenci.email='" + mainform.Username + "' AND Enrollment.dersId='"+listBox1.SelectedValue+"'";
       string query = "INSERT INTO Enrollment(dersId,ogrenciId) VALUES (@dersId, @ogrenciId)";



       using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
            int result=0;
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query1, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                result=Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
                connection.Close();
            }
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dersId", listBox1.SelectedValue);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ogrenciId",result);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                PopulateList2();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint @hdkhardik

Comment: Please check your data, do you have the value in other table which you are trying to insert ?

Comment: yes , there is a student table which has the ID im trying to pass into command and there is an enrollment table which relates coarses with students, and they all have data inside.

Comment: okay so i checked the query1 is actual result it returns the id's of the students which already have coarses so i removed //Enrollment.dersId='"+listBox1.SelectedValue+"'// from the query and used your way ,it worked. Thanks !, i was trying to get it to work for hours

Answer (score 2):

You only need one sql command.  The structure would be like this:

```
insert into table2
(field1, field2)
select value1, value2
etc
```

Comment: value1 is dependent on user so i can't use a select in insert.User is selecting a coarse from a listbox then clicks add,button should get the coarse id and logged in users student ID,then insert them both into enrollment table.so value1 is users selection but value2 is not.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int id;   
 using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
           using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query1, connection))
           {
             connection.Open();
             id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar()); //I guess it returns only 1 id?..  
           }
```

Comment: i get / The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint / when i use this and the solution below.I tried that myself before but i don't understand why it doesnt work.If i hard code the query1's result into that command it works perfectly.

Comment: have you checked if query1 actually returns correct id?

Comment: Yes, it returns the id that i want but i can't get it to work in buttonClick event.